# SharePoint 2010 : October 2018 CU Build Number

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, build-number

I just updated the SharePoint 2010 with October 2018 CU. Went through successfully and also the Configuration Wizard was successful. My question is the Configuration DB version in Servers in Farm remains the same. It has not updated to the newer number. Does it mean that Oct 2018 CU does not update the schema of Configuration DB? When I navigate to the Manage Patch status, I am able to see the KB4461464 as installed against different components. I am just thinking it is good. Appreciate if you can confirm that.

Regards
Vj

Comment: Do you see any action required in central admin? [centraladminurl]/_admin/DatabaseStatus.aspx

Comment: I do not. It says No action Required.

Comment: what was the patch level before and build number?

Comment: The prior CU was March 2018 and the build number was 14.0.7196.5000. It is still the same. But I did checked the components updated in the Manage Patch Status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The only component directly accessing the configuration database is the SharePoint foundation component" But as you know their is no SharePoint foundation patch released in the [October 2018 for SharePoint Server 2010](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2018/10/09/october-2018-cu-for-sharepoint-2010-product-family-is-available-for-download/). So in this case configuration database version will not change and remain same.

Read the below article, which explain int he detail.
[Common question: why does the version number on the "Servers in Farm" page not change after installing October CU?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2014/10/23/common-question-why-does-the-version-number-on-the-servers-in-farm-page-not-change-after-installing-october-cu/)